# Plugin methods are missing in Firefox 3.6

Tags: firefox, plugins, firefox3.6

We have a plugin that we use to enable printing and saving from our
app. We instantiate it using  tag with all needed attributes,
and then call Save() or Print() method on the document.embeds[0]
object.

This used to work perfectly on Firefox 3.5 and earlier, but it no
longer works in Firefox 3.6. In 3.6, document.embeds[0].Save is null,
that is our custom methods are not defined on this object.

Any idea why this happens, and what has changed in Firefox 3.6 that
causes it? Any idea on how to debug it and find the cause? And most
important, any idea of a workaround that will allow us to access this
methods?

Thanks,
splintor

Answer (score 0):

Got [an answer](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.plugins/msg/5424fe2ff0dd7355) in mozilla.dev.tech.plugins forum - Firefox 3.6 removes support for XPCOM. We will need to change our plugin according to one of the options suggested in the answer.